# Unable to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.2

Tags: apt, upgrade

I can't for the life of me figure out how or what to remove or install to fix this upgrade, here is the output from `grep  Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`:

```
Broken dpkg:amd64 Breaks on libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 < 1.6.14 @ii mK > (< 1.7~b)
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:4.8.7+dfsg-20~)
Broken libgcc1:amd64 Conflicts on libgcc1:i386 < 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 -> 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libuno-sal3:amd64 Breaks on uno-libs3:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mK >
Broken libqtgui4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-network:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libkdecore5:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.0)
Broken libqt4-xml:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqtdbus4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-declarative:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libkdeui5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken qt-at-spi:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8~)
Broken libqt4-svg:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libattica0.4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.7)
Broken libkio5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1)
Broken qdbus:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libsolid4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.0)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu1.3 @ii mK > (< 3.30.1.2-2~)
Broken libkpimsmtp5abi1:amd64 Breaks on libkpimsmtp5:amd64 < 17.12.2-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 19.12.3~)
Broken libkwinglutils12:amd64 Breaks on libkwinglutils11:amd64 < 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 @ii mK >
Broken libkwinxrenderutils12:amd64 Breaks on libkwinxrenderutils11:amd64 < 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 @ii mK >
Broken libqt4-script:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libkwineffects12:amd64 Breaks on libkwineffects11:amd64 < 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libkparts4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libphonon4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.1)
Broken libqt4-sql:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libdmtx0b:amd64 Conflicts on libdmtx0a:amd64 < 0.7.4-2 @ii mK >
Broken breeze:amd64 Breaks on plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop:amd64 < 4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.13.0~)
Broken software-properties-qt:amd64 Conflicts on software-properties-kde:amd64 < 0.96.24.32.14 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.96.25)
Broken python2-minimal:amd64 Breaks on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
Broken libglvnd-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl-dev:amd64 < none | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 1.3.0-1)
Broken libpython2-stdlib:amd64 Breaks on libpython-stdlib:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii gK > (< 2.7.15-2)
Broken libqt4-opengl:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libtinyxml2-6a:amd64 Conflicts on libtinyxml2-6:amd64 < 6.0.0+dfsg-1 @ii mK >
Broken libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libldb2:amd64 Breaks on libldb1:amd64 < 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.2 @ii mK > (< 2:2~)
Broken libqtwebkit4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1)
Broken libkjsapi4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkdewebkit5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libhfstospell10:amd64 Conflicts on libhfstospell:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 Depends on libqt4-sql:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libkf5torrent6:amd64 Breaks on libktorrent6:amd64 < 2.1.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libkpty4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libqt4-qt3support:amd64 Depends on libqt4-network:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libknewstuff3-4:amd64 Depends on libattica0.4:amd64 < 0.4.2-2 @ii mR > (>= 0.4.2)
Broken libqca2:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.0)
Broken libkemoticons4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libkdnssd4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken phonon:amd64 Depends on libphonon4:amd64 < 4:4.10.0-2 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.10.0-2)
Broken libkpmcore9:amd64 Breaks on libkpmcore7:amd64 < 3.3.0-2ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libqalculate20-data:amd64 Breaks on libqalculate6-data:amd64 < 0.9.10-1 @ii mK >
Broken libadplug-2.3.1-0:amd64 Conflicts on libadplug-2.2.1-0v5:amd64 < 2.2.1+dfsg3-1~build0.18.04.1 @ii mK >
Broken freerdp2-x11:amd64 Conflicts on freerdp-x11:amd64 < 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-15ubuntu1.18.04.2 @ii mK >
Broken libkcmutils4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkrosscore4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libkjsembed4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gsettings:amd64 < none | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 @un uH >
Broken fwupdate:amd64 Breaks on fwupdate-signed:amd64 < 12-7~ubuntu18.04.3 @ii mK >
Broken fwupdate:amd64 Breaks on libfwup1:amd64 < 12-3bionic2 @ii mK > (< 12-5)
Broken libplasma3:amd64 Depends on libkcmutils4:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkfile4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkhtml5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken plasma-scriptengine-javascript:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.14.38~)
Broken libkdesu5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libqca2-plugins:amd64 Depends on libqca2:amd64 < 2.1.3-2ubuntu2 @ii mR > (= 2.1.3-2ubuntu2)
Broken libknotifyconfig4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken kdelibs-bin:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libktexteditor4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkdeclarative5:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libglvnd-core-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libkf5mimetreeparser5abi2:amd64 Depends on kf5-messagelib-data:amd64 < 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu3 -> 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu3)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken phonon-backend-gstreamer:amd64 Depends on phonon-backend-gstreamer-common:amd64 < 4:4.9.0-1 -> 4:4.10.0-1build1 @ii umU > (= 4:4.9.0-1)
Broken libkde3support4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libkmediaplayer4:amd64 Depends on libkdeui5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libthreadweaver4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.8.0)
Broken libkntlm4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libpolkit-qt-1-1:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1)
Broken libkf5pimtextedit5abi2:amd64 Depends on libkf5pimtextedit-data:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libkactivities6:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.13.2)
Broken libntrack-qt4-1:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.5.3)
Broken kde-runtime:amd64 Depends on plasma-scriptengine-javascript:amd64 < 4:17.08.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:17.08.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken kdoctools:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken kdelibs5-plugins:amd64 Depends on kdelibs-bin:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1)
Broken libqt4-designer:amd64 Depends on libqt4-script:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken libkxmlrpcclient4:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.14.2)
Broken kde-style-breeze-qt4:amd64 Depends on kde-style-breeze:amd64 < 4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1 -> 4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1)
Broken libkf5gravatar5:amd64 Depends on libkf5gravatar-data:amd64 < 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < 1:20.0~git200108124800.ad4fb7e~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken libkf5ldap5:amd64 Depends on libkf5ldap-data:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libapt-inst2.0:amd64 Depends on libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 < 1.6.14 @ii mR > (>= 1.1~exp9)
Broken libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libkpimkdav5:amd64 Depends on libkpimkdav-data:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 -> 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 @ii umU > (= 1:12.2-9~bionic1)
Broken sni-qt:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu3~)
Broken libcupsmime1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libkonq-common:amd64 Depends on libkdecore5:amd64 < 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1 @ii mR > (>= 4:4.14.22~)
Broken libkpimgapicore5:amd64 Depends on libkpimgapi-data:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libept1.5.0:amd64 Depends on libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 < 1.6.14 @ii mR > (>= 1.1~exp9)
Broken libcupsppdc1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libkf5alarmcalendar5abi1:amd64 Depends on libkf5alarmcalendar-data:amd64 < 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 -> 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1)
Broken libkf5messageviewer5abi4:amd64 Depends on kf5-messagelib-data:amd64 < 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu3 -> 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu3)
Broken libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 Depends on libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 < 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5 -> 0.105-26ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5)
Broken libqalculate6:amd64 Depends on libqalculate6-data:amd64 < 0.9.10-1 @ii mR >
Broken libebook-1.2-19:amd64 Depends on libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 @ii mR > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libcupscgi1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on libqtdbus4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on qdbus:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqtdbus4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken qdbus:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken libopengl-dev:amd64 Breaks on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH Ib > (< 1.3.0-1)
Broken libglvnd-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd0:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 -> 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU > (= 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken psensor:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 @ii mR >
Broken lm-sensors:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
Broken pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 -> 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 @ii umU > (= 1:12.2-9~bionic1)
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on libqtdbus4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on qdbus:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqtdbus4:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libqtdbus4:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken qdbus:amd64 Depends on libqt4-xml:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken qdbus:amd64 Depends on libqtcore4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
Broken ksysguardd:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
Broken libhpmud0:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64 < none | 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 5.8+dfsg)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2)
Broken libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken libsane-hpaio:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0)
Broken ksysguard:amd64 Depends on ksysguardd:amd64 < 4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1 | 4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (= 4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1)
Broken libglvnd-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd0:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 -> 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU > (= 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 @ii mR >
Broken pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 -> 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 @ii umU > (= 1:12.2-9~bionic1)
Broken libqt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on libqtdbus4:amd64 < 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1)
Broken libsane:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64 < none | 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 5.8+dfsg)
Broken sane-utils:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.27)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libglvnd-dev:amd64 < 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0 | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken qtbase5-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl-dev:amd64 < none | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH >
Broken libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64 Depends on qtbase5-dev:amd64 < 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 | 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (= 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1)
Broken libgles-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl-dev:amd64 < none | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH >
Broken simple-scan:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)
Broken libkf5sane5:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)
Broken freeglut3-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < 1:20.0~git200108124800.ad4fb7e~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken freeglut3-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl-dev:amd64 < none | 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH >
Broken qt5-default:amd64 Depends on qtbase5-dev:amd64 < 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 | 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (= 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1)
Broken qt5-default:amd64 Depends on qtbase5-gles-dev:amd64 < none | 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 5.12.8+dfsg)
Broken libsane1:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2)
Broken libqt5gui5-gles:amd64 Conflicts on libqt5gui5:amd64 < 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 -> 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 @ii umU >
Broken paprefs:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio-module-gconf:amd64 < 1:12.2-9~bionic1 @ii mR >
Broken cuda-samples-10-1:amd64 Depends on freeglut3-dev:amd64 < 2.8.1-3 @ii mR >
Broken skanlite:amd64 Depends on libkf5sane5:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu1 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umR > (>= 5.1.0)
Broken cuda-documentation-10-1:amd64 Depends on cuda-samples-10-1:amd64 < 10.1.105-1 @ii mR >
Broken cuda-toolkit-10-1:amd64 Depends on cuda-samples-10-1:amd64 < 10.1.105-1 @ii mR > (>= 10.1.105)
Broken multimc:amd64 Depends on qt5-default:amd64 < 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 | 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 @ii umR >
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)
Broken sane-utils:amd64 Depends on libsane1:amd64 < 1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.4 | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @ii umR > (>= 1.0.27)
Broken simple-scan:amd64 Depends on libsane1:amd64 < 1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.4 | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @ii umR > (>= 1.0.24)
Broken cuda-10-1:amd64 Depends on cuda-toolkit-10-1:amd64 < 10.1.105-1 @ii mR > (>= 10.1.105)
Broken cuda:amd64 Depends on cuda-10-1:amd64 < 10.1.105-1 @ii mR > (>= 10.1.105)
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64 < none | 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uH > (>= 1.0.24)
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64 < 1.3.3-2build1 | 1.4.4-2 @ii umR > (>= 0.1.30)
Broken indicator-bluetooth:amd64 Depends on unity-control-center:amd64 < none | 15.04.0+19.10.20190921-0ubuntu3 @un uH >
Broken indicator-bluetooth:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken budgie-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 < 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 | 1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2 @ii umR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 < 6.10.2-1build1 @ii gR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 < 6.9.5-1build3 @ii gR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii gR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-23:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 < 19.1.0+git1910171153.b467d25~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 < 1:19.1.0+git1910171152.b9bd809~b~padoka0 @ii mR >
```

and the tail end of main.log:

```
2021-08-02 19:08:28,676 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:31,815 DEBUG openCache()
2021-08-02 19:08:32,287 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-147 with 
2021-08-02 19:08:32,287 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-151 with 4.15.0-147
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 70830
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 INFO checking for python-dbg (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 INFO checking for python-doc (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 INFO checking for python-minimal (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,401 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,422 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,422 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,441 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2021-08-02 19:08:32,442 INFO checking for python-dev (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,442 INFO checking for libpython-dev (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,442 INFO checking for libpython-stdlib (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,442 INFO removing libpython-stdlib because None is being installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,442 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-stdlib' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO checking for libpython-dbg (auto_inst=False)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO checking for python-dbg (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO checking for python-doc (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO checking for python-minimal (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,461 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,462 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO checking for python-dev (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO checking for libpython-dev (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO checking for libpython-stdlib (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO removing libpython-stdlib because None is being installed
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-stdlib' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2021-08-02 19:08:32,481 INFO checking for libpython-dbg (auto_inst=True)
2021-08-02 19:08:33,579 DEBUG Installing 'xserver-xorg-video-all' (Distro KeepInstalledPkgs rule)
2021-08-02 19:08:33,676 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
2021-08-02 19:08:33,679 DEBUG abort called
2021-08-02 19:08:33,685 DEBUG openCache()
2021-08-02 19:08:35,352 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-147 with 
2021-08-02 19:08:35,352 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-151 with 4.15.0-147
2021-08-02 19:08:35,517 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 104743
```

Apologies for asking the same question as several others, but I couldn't get the fixes I found to work, so some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are doing the release upgrade and what exactly have you tried already to fix the errors?

Comment: Did you remember to uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu and wrong-version packages? Those are the usual culprit. There is no single magic shell incantation to "fix" it, or apt would have already fixed it for you. You must understand the package conflict that you created in order to resolve it..

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep padoka0` and `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dev` to the question.

Comment: You didn't tell us if it's a desktop or server (packages feel more like desktop); I'd explore your sources (lines of output for that wasn't included) as some 3rd party sources are KNOWN/documented to block upgrade (eg. graphics drivers from oibaf) and need to be removed before upgrade as per prior comment.